# How to read and use a Phase / Vectorscope

Tags: mixing, stereo, mastering

I been using Izotope Ozone 4 for some time, but I'm still a bit intimidated by the Vectorscope in the stereo-imaging section.

When Mastering / Mixing a signal...

- What "lissajous shape" are you trying to achieve?
- And which ones should you absolutely avoid?
- Should some phasing switches be used while verifying your signal (toggle L/R channels, Mono, etc)?

I understand it is used to eliminate Phasing Issues, but how do you actually achieve this? Is this something that has to be typically verified and fixed *per instruments* **or** on the *overall master* mix?

Any free online resources on this subject would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is also called a "Goniometer". My bad!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lissajous shape is generated by graphing the left signal on one axis against the right signal on the other axis.  So consider a few scenarios for a sine wave tone.

- **Mono signal:** L is always equal to R, so the point (L, R) is always on the x=y line, so the plot is a straight line.  Vectorscopes usually rotate the axes 45 degrees, so x=y goes straight up and down instead of 45 degrees.
- **180 degrees out of phase:** L is always equal to -R, so again a straight line but on the rotated axes the line x=-y goes straight left and right
- **90 degrees out of phase:** L is following R (or vice versa) by 90 degrees, so the plot is a circle.

So "vertically-oriented" patterns indicate in-phaseness, "rounder" patterns are out of phase to some extent, "horizontally-oriented" patterns are out of phase to the point of cancelling each other out.

More complex frequency content will make this look like a mess... phase relationships are wavelength-dependent, so when some are out of phase, others are in phase.  You want to look at single frequencies or narrow bands.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much for the detailed answer. So is reading a vectorscope in soloed "multiband" effect processor (say 4 seperate ranges) sufficiently narrow to measure for phase-cancellations? Or would it be better to pass it through a thin Q range frequency sweeped via an EQ?